# Carry over data without using for loop

Tags: c++, iterator, containers

I have a vector of strings and a vector of person.

```
vector<std::string> names
vector<Person> persons
```

Each Person object has a name field. Now I want to populate names vector from persons. Instead of using a for loop, any other way to do it?

Comment: What's wrong with a for loop?

Comment: You can write a custom constructor / assignment operator so you can construct `Person` from a `std::string` or a `std::string` from a `Person`. Probably not what you *really* want though.

Comment: But don't do that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree. Don't do that. But the question said "any other way to do it?" so I just thought I'd mention it, since it is *a* way (although a bad one). I didn't make it an answer for a reason. ;-)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Better with the last sentence :P Maybe it's just me though - I seem to be on a big "cut it out with all the member conversion utilities" kick lately

Comment: How is this question "too broad"?

Answer (score 7):

Sure! The standard algorithms are your friend; in this case, it's [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
// You'll need:
//   <vector>
//   <algorithm>
//   <iterator>

const std::vector<Person> people = getPeople();

std::vector<std::string> names;
names.reserve(people.size());

std::transform(
   std::begin(people),
   std::end(people),
   std::back_inserter(names),
   [](const Person& person) { return person.name; }
);
```

This will ultimately use a `for` loop inside, it's just hidden from you.

There's no constructor of `std::vector` that can do it in one fell swoop, though, sorry. You can always write a `vector<string> GetNames(const vector<People>&)` utility function to wrap it all up, then it's just `auto names = GetNames(people)` at your callsite.

---

It may be tempting instead to take a shortcut and just add a conversion operator to `Person`. This will work, and allow you to initialise `names` from a range of `Person`s directly.

Personally, though, I find that implicit conversions are an absolute menace, and this particular implicit conversion doesn't seem to make logical sense for the class (among other things, it's narrowing, because it discards all non-name parts of people).

It's the sort of shortcut that feels like a clever, cheap win … then in three years' time you'll realise that, all along, this was the start of a massive mountain of technical debt in your design, that you can no longer untangle. I would not recommend that.

---

Also, honestly, a `for` loop is fine. It's *less* code. And more people will know what it does.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I'll take it! 

Comment: Nice solution, however isn't transform implemented based on looping?

Comment: @JVApen Yes, and I said that in the answer. Any solution will be based on looping. A problem like this is literally what looping is for. How do you do it without looping at _some_ level of abstraction? (Hint: you can't) Hopefully the OP's concern was that of complexity and/or terseness at the callsite and not much more (but then, as I also point out, the irony is that the `for` loop is probably the simplest and tersest solution!)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I assumed, unless you do loop unrolling

Comment: @JVApen How do you unroll a loop of runtime bounds? The resulting machine code will be, um, the same as that of a loop 

Comment: You don't have more than 10.000 people, right? Just some if-statements in between. (I really hope no one is taking this serious)

Comment: _"You don't have more than 10.000 people, right?"_ The OP didn't say and, even if they did, the computer wouldn't know that!

Comment: `mem_fn` may be simpler than a lambda.

Answer (score 2):

A for loop is really very simple, and it's what I would personally go for:

```
const std::vector<Person> persons = ...
std::vector<std::string> names;
names.reserve (persons.size ());

for (const auto &person : persons)
    names.push_back (person.name);
```

Compare brevity and readability with `std::transform` code in the other answer here.

But if you really hate that loop, you can use [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) instead:

```
std::for_each (persons.begin(), persons.end(),
    [&names] (const auto &person) { names.push_back (person.name); });
```

Comment: Those spaces before `(` are giving me a headache :P But I bet you get that a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate `names` by adding `operator string()` to `Person` :

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
    public:
        string name;

        operator string() { return name; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Person> persons{ {"Pete"}, {"Edna"}, {"John"} };
    vector<string> names(persons.begin(), persons.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't introduce surprising implicit conversions! Especially narrowing ones (we assume `Person` has other members in reality)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, It is one way to do what he asked.  Also, it's much simpler than the solution you propose.

Comment: Yes, it is, and there is nothing wrong with posting it as an answer. But, since we're teaching, I'd prefer that we be up-front about the potential consequences of taking the "cheap" solution. That's just, like, my opinion, man!

Comment: No worries I've added that note to my own answer now so it's cool :)